# How to use scrollRevealJS alongside AnimateCSS?

Tags: css, animation, scroll, animate.css, scrollreveal.js

I love both the [scrollRevealJS](https://github.com/jlmakes/scrollReveal.js) and [AnimateCSS](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css) libraries for animations, however, I would like to use them both on one element. For example, I have a div `<div class="animated fadeInDown" data-sr='enter top reset'>Lorem Ipsum</div>`. For some reason, adding the Animate CSS classes `animated fadeInDown` ignores scrollReveal's data attribute. How am I able to use both the classes and data attributes of both libraries?

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I have the following style applied:

`[data-sr] { visibility: hidden; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ScrollRevealJS library does not provide default functionality to work with AnimateCss. Instead of ScrollRevealJS you can use Wow.js library – it works with AnimateCss. The problem with Wow.js is that a reset option is not available.

Comment: Yes, I've tried WOW.js, but it not having the reset option is the exact reason why I moved away from it.

Comment: Did you manage to get ScrollRevealJS and AnimateCSS working together to reset the animations on scroll?